# AWS index not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I created a bucket on AWS, specified index file (`index.html`) in bucked settings (Static Website Hosting > Enable website hosting > Index Document: index.html), have set up Route 53, linked a domain name. But now when I try to access the website with `mydomain.com` get this:

```
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Access Denied</Message>
    <RequestId>798B815A42872AC2</RequestId>
    <HostId>
        0TAuP9C2fyTeeWf2fPv7xC6XZ2Ccax9qqsrYtQy9ZisZDNi4NpqhcX1TfOB41bc4Syx28DNQeH8=
    </HostId>
</Error>
```

`mydomain.com/index.html` works ok

Comment: what does the route53 link look like? a cname? paste its target. (bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com, for instance)

Answer (score 1):

Edit your bucket policy and make sure to have something like

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mydomain.com/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

replace `mydomain.com` with your actual domain name

Answer (score 1):

You also need to give permission to view the content (AWS gives no one access by default). One way is to add a bucket policy in the bucket permissions:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddPerm",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::YOURBUCKETNAME/*"
        }
    ]
}
```